# How do I play a sound over the same sound?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So I'm trying to get a sound to play at the same time, at different intervals. It's the exact same file, though I'm unsure how to play it multiple times without more than one  tag.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually very simple. Here is the code:

*(You can click multiple times on the "Play" button to test)*

```js
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    var audio = new Audio("https://www.gnu.org/music/free-software-song-herzog.ogg");
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Audio</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Play</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like your solution much better :)

Comment: Do you like the Free Software Song? xD

Comment: I really like how this works (nice music btw), though is there a way I can use a sleep function to have the sound play automatically on page load, and it overlaps once or twice, and it loops?

Comment: To play the song on page load, you can simply remove the click listener. Then, if you need to play it again and again, use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). You should also read the documentation about the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement). ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using a setTimeout() function? 
for example if you play the sound, then moments later the same sound file is played.

```
var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
function PlaySound() {
setTimeout(function(){ sound.play(); }, 500);
setTimeout(function(){ sound.play(); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: the sound only plays once